# How to automatically change the format or encode the excel cell value while writing it to CSV file

Tags: excel, csv, perl, export-to-csv

My script is breaking when excel cell has double quotes in their value and quotes. I had to explicitly write a function to handle commas in OUTFILE. Is there any way I can provide cell value and automatically it can be encoded to CSV format.
example-

1. cell->value - Student GOT 8 MARKS in math, 7 in Spanish

   Desired Correct CSV format-> "Student GOT 8 MARKS in math, 7 in Spanish".
2. cell->value - Student GOT 8 MARKS in "math", 7 in "Spanish"

   Desired Correct CSV format-> "Student GOT 8 MARKS in ""math"", 7 in ""Spanish""".

I wrote my function to find COMMAS in cell value and if it exits then put the string in double-quotes. I wanted to avoid it in case there are any built functions of CSV writer.

```
   #!/home/utils/perl-5.08
   use Text::CSV_XS;
   use Text::CSV;
   use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
   use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
   use CGI qw(:standard);
   use DBI;
   use DBD::CSV;
   
   my $student_excel_file = "";
   my $csv = "";
   
   $student_excel_file='ABC.xlsm';
   
      $csv = $student_excel_file;
      $csv =~ s/.xlsx$/_22june_intermediate_xlsxtocsv.csv/;
      $csv =~ s/.xlsm$/_22june_intermediate_xlsmtocsv.csv/;
      my $parser_1   = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();
      my $workbook_1 = $parser_1->parse($student_excel_file);
      printf "$csv\n";
      print "writing out the new csv file $csv given prvs xlsm file\n";
      
      my $csv_1 = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => "\r\n", sep_char  => ',' });
      
      open my $fh, ">:encoding(utf-8)", $csv or die "failed to create $csv: $!";
      #open OUTFILE, "> $student_excel_out_csv_file" or die "ERROR: can't the student;'s CSV file:- $student_excel_out_csv_file.\n";
      
      if ( !defined $workbook_1 ) 
      {
         die $parser_1->error(), ".\n";
      }
    
      my $worksheet_1=$workbook_1->worksheet(0);
      my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet_1->row_range();
      my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet_1->col_range();
      printf("Copyig Sheet: %s from the provided PRVS \n", $worksheet_1->{Name});
      my $reached_end_of_sheet = 0;
      my $concurentEmptyLineCount = 0;
      $col_max=65;
      #$row_max=2;
   my(@heading) = ("CodeA", "CodeB", "Name", "Count", "Pos", "Orientation");
   $csv_1->print($fh, \@heading);
   my(@datarow) = ("A", "B", "Abelone", 3, "(6,9)", "NW");
   $csv_1->print($fh, \@datarow); 
   my(@datarow_1) = ("A", "B", "Abelone", 3, "WORKS - ""what"" - lets", "_2NW");
   $csv_1->print($fh, \@datarow_1);
   for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
    
       my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
       my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
       printf("Sheet: %s\n", $worksheet->{Name});
   
       my $sheet_write = $excel_2->add_worksheet($worksheet->{Name});
       # my $format = $sheet_write->add_format();
   
          for my $row_1 ( 1 .. $row_max ) 
      {
         if($reached_end_of_sheet)
         {
            last;
         }
         for my $col_1 ( $col_min .. $col_max ) 
            {
               my $cell_1 = $worksheet_1->get_cell( $row_1, 0 );
               next unless $cell_1;
               $concurentEmptyLineCount=0;
               my $cell_2 = $worksheet_1->get_cell( $row_1, $col_1);
               my $cell2_value =$cell_2 -> {Val};
               print $cell_2 -> {Val};
               $csv_1->print ($fh, \$cell2_value );
               # if(defined $cell2_value)
               # {
                  # if($cell2_value=~ m/,/)
                  # {
                      # $cell2_value=qq("$cell2_value");
                  # }
                  
                  # printf OUTFILE "%s,", $cell2_value;
               # }
               # else
               # {
                  # printf OUTFILE ",";}
               # }
               my $cell_3 = $worksheet_1->get_cell( $row_1, 0 );
               $concurentEmptyLineCount++;
               if($concurentEmptyLineCount > 20)
               {
                  $reached_end_of_sheet = 1;
               }
               next unless $cell_3;
               #printf OUTFILE "\n";
               $csv_1->print ($fh, "\n" );
       }
   
   
   #close OUTFILE;
   
   close $fh;
   
   
   exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`combine()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#combine) to quote the fields. For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
my @fields = (
    q[Student GOT 8 MARKS in math, 7 in Spanish],
    q[Student GOT 8 MARKS in "math", 7 in "Spanish"],
);
for my $field (@fields) {
    my $success = $csv->combine($field);
    if (!$success) {
        die "Failed to quote field: " . $field;
    }
    say "Result: ", $csv->string();
}
```

**Output**:

```
Result: "Student GOT 8 MARKS in math, 7 in Spanish"
Result: "Student GOT 8 MARKS in ""math"", 7 in ""Spanish"""
```